# Did the Wizarding World learn about Voldemort's Horcruxes after his defeat?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and The Deathly Hallows*, the following words are uttered by Harry Potter before he defeats Voldemort:

> “There are no more Horcruxes. It’s just you
>   and me. Neither can live while the other survives, and one of us is about to
>   leave for good. . . .”
>
> *Harry Potter and The Deathly Hallows*

When he says that, everyone who is in the Great Hall can hear him and there are bound to be some people - most likely adults - who know what a Horcrux is so they won't dismiss the word in the midst of the confrontation. So it is likely that the fact that Voldemort had created Horcruxes and especially more than one, is something that the few who were in the Great Hall know.

But is the whole story something that eventually becomes history? Does the fact that Voldemort created 7 Horcruxes become widely known to people or do the people that were there keep it as hushed as possible?

If it becomes common knowledge, perhaps written in history books and told to young children, wouldn't that make it even easier for dark wizards to get inspired and create their own Horcruxes and even push their limits even further? (As far as we know before Voldemort even the darkest of wizards had created 1 Horcrux).
Also wouldn't they learn from Volemort's mistakes and create Horcruxes out of less significant objects?

So how much of the story becomes widely known?

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive, covering both the books and pottermore. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 8):

The best evidence on the subject would suggest that the Wizarding world *in general* were aware of Voldemort's Horcrux plan.

### During his final encounter with Voldemort, Harry and Voldemort discuss Horcruxes *in front of a crowd of onlookers*.

> ‘I don’t want anyone else to try to help,’ Harry said loudly, and in the total silence his voice carried like a trumpet call. ‘It’s got to be like this. It’s got to be me.’
>   Voldemort hissed.
>   ‘Potter doesn’t mean that,’ he said, his red eyes wide. ‘That isn’t how he works, is it? Who are you going to use as a shield today, Potter?’
>   **‘Nobody,’ said Harry simply. ‘There are no more Horcruxes. It’s just you and me. Neither can live while the other survives, and one of us is about to leave for good …’**
>   ‘One of us?’ jeered Voldemort, and his whole body was taut and his red eyes stared, a snake that was about to strike. ‘You think it will be you, do you, the boy who has survived by accident, and because Dumbledore was pulling the strings?’

So we know that everyone who survived the Battle of Hogwarts would have been aware that Voldemort was using Horcruxes (whatever those are).

---

### A [Daily Prophet article](http://uk.complex.com/pop-culture/2014/07/read-jk-rowlings-new-harry-potter-story-here) ("***Dumbledore’s Army Reunites at Quidditch World Cup Final"*** originally published on Pottermore.com) also contains the following open reference to Horcruxes

> *"Was the work of the Auror Department too much for a man who has
>   admitted that the destruction of He Who Could Not Be Named's Horcruxes
>   'took its toll' on him?"*

Since this was written by JKR herself, we can quite happily assume that the entire wizarding world was aware of the existence of Voldemort's Horcrux plan after his defeat.

Comment: For the first bit, we can at least say that anyone from the crowd who remembered that particular remark from what was by any standards a very hectic and traumatic night would know that Voldemort was using Horcruxes. Honestly, though, I don't think that would be very many people. Sure, everyone was on tenterhooks at the moment, but I think most would forget the details once the realisation of Voldemort’s death and the practicalities of tending to the dead and all the aftermath kicked in. Second point is quite irrefutable, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Since they have the magical ability to [extract **perfect** memories](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Memory_extraction_spell) and review them [endlessly from multiple angles](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Pensieve), the ability to accurately remember an incident really isn't much of a problem.

Comment: That is true. Though I wonder if anyone would _want_ to relive that night.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - At the very least we know that the wizarding press would pay fine fat fees for the chance to review the memories of someone who was there.

Comment: Also very true.

Comment: @Valorum It would depend on whether a Pensieve is something they could buy in Diagon Alley or a truly rare object. Unless there are easier ways to view memories.

Comment: @System - That sounds like the making of two good questions; "How rare are Pensieves?" / "Are there other ways to view memories than a Penseive?"

Comment: @Valorum yes! But I have a 40 minute between questions limit!

Comment: @System - Ooh. That gives me a few minutes to start thinking up an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

I find it rather surprising that Voldemort's Horcrux(es) were a secret at any point after his return become confirmed at the end of OotP.

It can't be that **nobody** from the Ministry knows about Horcruxes, and after Harry's interview with Rita Skeeter was published, someone should have asked the question, "What can keep a wizard alive when his body has been destroyed."